# How do I make an HTML element come on top of the other?

Tags: html, css

I have a css3 moving clouds background like this one for my site.

- http://cssdeck.com/labs/animated-clouds-background-pure-css3
- http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/pure-css3-animated-clouds-background

However, the clouds keep coming on top of the text and I cannot see any text when they hover over it. Is there a way to make these elements come on top of the clouds?

Comment: You need to share your code or your question will be closed soon

Comment: (before this question is closed) `z-index`

Comment: There are few cases where `z-index` _should_ be used. When you want to stick some element (clouds) between an element (background) and its child (text) is one of the cases where it can be used

Comment: You could reduce the z-index of the cloud or increase the z-index of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your HTML structure is like this:

```
<div id="sky-container">
  <div id="cloud-container">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<div id="text-container">
  ...
</div>
```

congratulations, you're already done, you just need to position them correctly (absolute positioning). The text should already appear above the clouds. If your HTML is like this:

```
<div id="cloud-container">
  ...
</div>
<div class="background">
  <div class="background">
     <div class="text">
        ...
     </div>
  <div class="text">
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

i.e. if you don't have a single background, you can still insert the clouds between the background and the text. You just need to separate the background from the text in the HTML. You can use a `z-index` to place the clouds between the text and the background:

```
.background{
  z-index:0;
}
#cloud-container{
  z-index:1;
}
.text{
  z-index:2;
}
```

Since the default `z-index` is 0, if you know the cloud container will be the last element on the page (and is the one that gets `position:absolute`), you can simplify the CSS to:

```
.text{
  z-index:1;
}
```

**An element with a z-index also needs to have its `position` property explicitly set** to `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! For future reference, put the content within another div called container, set position to relativeand z-index 1. Thanks again!